# On Refresh: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express, endpoint

I'm trying to create an API endpoint that authenticates a user given email and password parameters and returns a JSON response on the success of the authentication. But every time I call the same endpoint twice (by refreshing or calling it from the same page twice), I get:
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.`

I've looked online and found several solutions to remove res.send redundancies or using res.json. None of them have worked.

```
app.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {

    let email = req.query.email;
    let password = req.query.password;

    con.connect(err => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'connection error'
            })
        }

        con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='${email}'`, (err) => {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                res.send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'account does not exist'
                })
            } else {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].password)) {
                    res.redirect('/dashboard')
                } else {
                    res.send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'incorrect password'
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

I am expecting a successful response, but I keep getting the error. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I faced issue like this before - it's a promise issue , your codes send response to the client twice

Comment: It's probably registering an error in con.connect and then still going on to con.query. You may have more luck if you return res.send, then the function will terminate.

Comment: Can I only have one res.send in the endpoint?

Comment: @HanWang you can only have one res.send that executes. You can have multiple in conditionals.

Comment: @CalIrvine that works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is caused by trying to send more than one response to a particular request.  In the code you show for this particular request handler, I see one place where you could be doing that.

If you get an error connecting, then you test for that and send an error response, but you don't return so the request handler continues into the rest of the handler and will then try to send another response.

You need to add a `return` or an `else` so that if there's a connection error, the code doesn't flow into the rest of the handler.

```
app.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {

    let email = req.query.email;
    let password = req.query.password;

    con.connect(err => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                success: false,
                message: 'connection error'
            })
            return;
        }

        con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='${email}'`, (err) => {
            if (result.length === 0) {
                res.send({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'account does not exist'
                })
            } else {
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].password)) {
                    res.redirect('/dashboard')
                } else {
                    res.send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'incorrect password'
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    })
```